# Angularjs UI router submodules and URLs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app where a module looks at the URL. If the URL has anything past the "Document" section then one state is set using the information beyond that URL. If the URL has nothing beyond that point, then another state is set. So the two URLs are ...

www.xyz.com/Document/

and

www.xyz.com/Document/someData

I am currently solving the problem as below. This works, but I really need the two states to be in the same module and I can't figure out how to make that happen.

So, instead of the second state applying to app.documentEmpty, I want it to apply to app.document.empty.

```
 angular
    .module('app.document', [
        'app.document.worksheet',
        'app.document.tableOfContents',
        'app.document.properties',
        'app.document.bibliography',
        'app.document.inputs',
        'app.document.datasets',
        'app.document.fileAsFunction',
        'app.document.importedFunctions',
         'app.document.directory'
       ])
    .config(config);


/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, msApiProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider)
{
$stateProvider.state('app.document', {
        url      : '/Document/{path:.*}/',
        views    : {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/document/worksheet/worksheet.html',
                controller : 'DocumentController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve  : {
            Documents: function (msApi)
            {
                return msApi.resolve('document.documents@get');
            },
            emptyDocuments: function (msApi)
            {
                return msApi.resolve('document.emptyList@get');
            }
        },
        bodyClass: 'worksheet'

    }).state('app.documentEmpty', {
        url      : '/Document/',
        views    : {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/document/documentEmpty.html',
                controller : 'DocumentController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve  : {
            Documents: function (msApi)
            {
                return msApi.resolve('document.documents@get');
            },
            emptyDocuments: function (msApi)
            {
                return msApi.resolve('document.emptyList@get');
            }
        },
        bodyClass: 'document'
    });
```

The problem is that whenever I remove the second state from above and replace it with something like what's below in the directory submodule, the URL is not recognized and the proper page is not loaded. There are several other submodules that do not depend upon URL and they work fine.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.document.directory', {
    url      : '/Document/',
    views    : {
        'content@app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/document/directory/directory.html',
             controller : 'DocumentController as vm'
        }
    },
    bodyClass: 'directory'

});
```

Is it not possible to route to submodules via URLs?

Comment: they should. not sure what went wrong, but you can definitely define your states in the submodules. The only gotcha is to make sure your state hierachy is well defined and your parent is not broken. Any error in the logs?

Comment: I tried defining the state in the submodule and in the parent. There are no errors, it just simply doesn't work when the submodule is defined as the URL with nothing after it.

Comment: I think I managed to figure out your problem already. Let me post an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused with `state` and `module`.

The dot notation in `ui-router` indicates `child` states. So when you are doing this: `$stateProvider.state('app.document.directory',{})`, the views will only be populated **IF** your `app.document` exists and it has a `ui-view` directive in it. Added to that, the url parameters set in the state object will be appended **AFTER** the url defined in `app.document` state.

Say for your example above, you have defined a state like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.document', {
        url      : '/Document/{path:.*}/',
        //... omitted for brevity
```

Now, this will work:

```
.state('app.documentEmpty', {
        url      : '/Document/',
        //... omitted for brevity
```

because `app.document` and `app.documentEmpty` are **sibling** states.

On the other hand, this will **not** work:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.document.directory', {
    url      : '/Document/',
    //... omitted for brevity
```

because `app.document.directory` is the **child** state of `app.document` (child states are defined by the dot notation, i.e `.directory`)

So in order to work, you have to rethink of your states hierarchy. In your `app.document.directory` module, define a state `app.documentDirectory` (note that there is no dot after the document):

```
  angular.module("app.document.directory",[])
    .config('$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
      $stateProvider.state('app.documentDirectory',{ //not app.document.directory, because this will make it a child state of app.document
        url:'/directory'
        //omitted for brevity
      })
    });
```

Comment: Near as I can tell, this is the "answer".